Arabic text causes uneven line spacing with glosses in gb4e
I'm using gb4e to glass text in Arabic using polyglossia in XeLaTeX. An example of a gloss of the sort I'm trying to put together is provided below:
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\glll \textarabic{بِسْمِ} \textarabic{اللَّهِ} \textarabic{الرَّحْمَٰنِ} \textarabic{الرَّحِيمِ}\\
bi-smi l-l\=ahi r-ra\d hm\=ani r-ra\d h\=imi\\
in-name.Gen.M.Sg.Const the-god.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-merciful.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-{be merciful}.Participle.Gen.M.Sg.Def\\
\trans `In the name of God, the merciful one, who is merciful'
\end{exe}

The issue I'm running into is that the variable size of the Arabic lettering, with the harakat above and below is causing the subsequent lines with the transcription and gloss to be misaligned as in the following image:

Is there any way to ensure more regular spacing between the target languages and the interlinear glosses? Or to make the Arabic text have a fixed line size?
added non-example
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex 
\glll \textarabic{بِسْمِ} \textarabic{اللَّهِ} \textarabic{الرَّحْمَٰنِ} \textarabic{الرَّحِيمِ}\\
bi-smi l-l\=ahi r-ra\d hm\=ani r-ra\d h\=imi\\
in-name.Gen.M.Sg.Const the-god.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-merciful.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-{be merciful}.Participle.Gen.M.Sg.Def\\
\trans `In the name of God, the merciful one, who is merciful'
\end{exe}
\end{document}



it would (as always) help if you provided a full example using some commonly available fonts so people don't have to guess how to reproduce the image shown.  If you globally increase baselineskip to be large enough to hold the arabic then you will get even spacing, but it might be a bit spacy. Or you could force that the depth of the descenders is ignored and then you would get even spacing but it might result in over-printing

I made a guess which produced something plausible but did not show the problem you asked about. Please edit that example to show the problem (the answer may be simply to revert that edit:-)

@DavidCarlisle Notice that your example does show a very slight vertical offset for the first gloss relative to the rest of the line. This difference disappears if you use LuaTeX.

@AlanMunn oh so it does.

@AlanMunn \nointerlineskip grrr

@AlanMunn better?

As Alan pointed out using Amiri there is a very slight offset. The code stacks boxes for the three lines at their natural height with no intervening skip, so it should really insert struts to ensure lines have similar heights. Here I use \strut for the second two lines using latin script and a custom \xstrut with a large depth for the first line, your font seems to have deeper descenders so you may need a larger strut here.  I made the strut visible {1pt} to make debugging easier, change to {0pt}  for the final version with an invisible strut.

\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xstrut{\rule[-10pt]{1pt}{20pt}}
\gdef\threesent#1\\ #2\\ #3\\{% #1 = first line, #2 = second line, #3 = third
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#1 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#2 \\%
    \getwords(\linethree,\eachwordthree)#3 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
         \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
         \lastword{\eachwordthree}{\linethree}{\wordthree}%
         \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{\unhbox\gline
                                    \hskip\glossglue
                                    \vtop{\hbox{\xstrut\box\wordone}%   % vtop was vbox
                                          \nointerlineskip
                                          \hbox{\strut\box\wordtwo}%
                                          \nointerlineskip
                                          \hbox{\strut\box\wordthree}%
                                         }%
                                   }%
         \testdone
         \ifnotdone
    \repeat
    \egroup % matches \bgroup in \gloss
   \gl@stop}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{exe}

\ex 
\glll \textarabic{بِسْمِ} \textarabic{اللَّهِ} \textarabic{الرَّحْمَٰنِ} \textarabic{الرَّحِيمِ}\\
bi-smi l-l\=ahi r-ra\d hm\=ani r-ra\d h\=imi\\
in-name.Gen.M.Sg.Const the-god.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-merciful.Gen.M.Sg.Def the-{be merciful}.Participle.Gen.M.Sg.Def\\
\trans `In the name of God, the merciful one, who is merciful'
\end{exe}
\end{document}

